# jquery execution order

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code:

```
function searchText() {
    if($('#searchtext').val() == null || $('#searchtext').val().trim() == '') {
         alert('must provide a text to search for');
     return false;
    }

    urllink='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + escape($('#searchtext').val().trim()) + '&callback=?';
    $('#results').html(urllink);

    $.getJSON(urllink,function(data) {
         var resultT = {};
         $('#results').html(data.results[0].profile_image_url);

         return data.results;
    });
}

$('#gosearch').click(function() {
    var data = searchText();
    if(data == null)
         alert('null');

    return false;
});
```

I have a breakpoint in firebug in `return data.results` of `searchText()`. But it seems that `searchText` is executed but I do not stop in my break point. It rather checks for data, which is `null`, and executes `alert('null')`. then it stops in my break point inside `searchText`.

Why is this happening? Can't I execute functions inside events and wait them to finish before moving to next line in code?

thanks

Comment: Please use the preview pane and properly format your post in future. Also I suggest you use braces with `if` statements for portability (`if (data == null) { alert('null'); }`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not realize that AJAX is **A**synchronous. So when `searchText()` returns the ajax request hasn't finished yet. You need to pass it a callback and execute that instead of doing `return data.results;`.

Here's an example:

```
function searchText(callback) {
    if ($('#searchtext').val() == null || $('#searchtext').val().trim() == '') {
        alert('must provide a text to search for');
        return false;
    }

    urllink = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + escape($('#searchtext').val().trim()) + '&callback=?';
    $('#results').html(urllink);

    $.getJSON(urllink, function (data) {
        var resultT = {};
        $('#results').html(data.results[0].profile_image_url);

        callback(data.results);
    });
}

$('#gosearch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchText(function(data) {
        if (data == null) alert('null');
        // do something with your data
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe that because this is a JSONP cross-domain request, I cannot perform synchronous $.ajax, am I right? I understand what you are saying, but then this means that you cannot write a nice structured program in javascript using ajax. everything must have a callback

Comment: Or use a synchronous XmlHttpRequest instead. "AJAX" is a misnomer.

Comment: from jquery documentation: Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

Comment: You should **never use synchronous ajax requests** as they may hang the browsser!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting data asynchronously from urllink and the function where the return data.result resides is a callback function which will be called when the call to the url is complete.

The subsequent code will not wait for the asynchronous call to complete.